# Hiding a Banner and Calling it back again?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, banner

I wanted to hide the banner if(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name=="Game"), but the scenes are loaded using Application.LoadLevelAsync.

Is it okay to create an update function that checks the name of loadlevelasync everytime before decides to hide or show the banner? or should I call hide only when game is loaded and show it after it exits??

Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `anync` scene loading. You can hide the banner when the scene the desired scene is loaded:

```
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    IEnumerator Start() 
    {
        AsyncOperation async = Application.LoadLevelAsync("MyBigLevel");
        yield return async;
        Debug.Log("Loading complete");
        // CALL THE CODE TO HIDE THE BANNER AT THIS POINT 
    }
}
```

Comment: then how should i show it back? when the scene is onDestroy?

Comment: There are several ways to do that for example : [SceneUnloaded](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager-sceneUnloaded.html) delegate. Or you can just create a `gameObject` and attach a script to it and then show banner in `OnDestroy` or `OnDisable` method

Comment: solve it, i called ondestroy on a gameobject of the scene to hide the banner

Comment: I am pleased to help. Kindly mark the answer correct.